# Issue in generating dynamic Html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In the below code I have a json array which holds `Name,FieldType,FieldValue`. And I want to create a dynamic table and assign values to it. I tried the below code which displays following data into table.
Json Array Format:

```
[{"Name":"Date","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"12-12-2013"},{"Name":"Details","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"test"},
{"Name":"Date","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"05-12-2015"},{"Name":"Details","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"test1"}]
```

Table Look like:

```
Date |  Details  |Date  | Details|
12-12-2013|test|05-12-2015|test1|
```

Table Should look like:

```
 Date |  Details  
    12-12-2013|test
 05-12-2015 |test1
```

Code:

```
 function LoadTableFields(sFieldID, Name, newdiv, FieldValue,TableValues) {

        var TblValues =JSON.parse( TableValues);

                alert(data.d);
                if (data.d != '') {
                    var TableDatas = JSON.parse(data.d);

                    var tHTML = '';
                    tHTML += '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table_' + sFieldID + '" name="' + Name + '"><thead><tr >';

                    $.each(TblValues, function (i, item) {
                        tHTML += '<th class="text-center">' + item.Name + '</th>';
                    });

                    tHTML += '</tr></thead><tbody><tr id="row_0" data-id="0">';

                    $.each(TblValues, function (i, item) {

                        if (item.FieldType == 'TextBox') {

                            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><input type="text" id=' + item.Name + '0' + '  value=' + item.FieldValue + ' name=' + item.Name + '0' + ' placeholder=' + item.Name + ' class="form-control"/></td>';
                        }                        else {
                            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + '></td>';
                        }

                    });

                    tHTML += '</tr></tbody></table>';
                    tHTML += '<a id="add_row_' + sFieldID + '" class="btn btn-default pull-left" onclick="AddNewTableRow(' + sFieldID + ');">Add Row</a><a id="delete_row_' + sFieldID + '" class="pull-right btn btn-default" onclick="DeleteTableRow(' + sFieldID + ');">Delete Row</a>';
                    newdiv.innerHTML += tHTML;

                    $('#divComplete').append(newdiv);



                }

            }
```

Comment: You have to create `tr` inside $.each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the headers you find. Then make sure the header row does not have duplicate values.

```
var TblValues = [{"Name":"Date","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"12-12-2013"},{"Name":"Details","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"test"},
{"Name":"Date","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"05-12-2015"},{"Name":"Details","FieldType":"TextBox","FieldValue":"test1"}];

tHTML = '';

var headers = [];

$.each(TblValues, function (i, item) {
        if ( headers.indexOf(item.Name) === -1) {
            headers.push(item.Name);
            tHTML += '<th class="text-center">' + item.Name + '</th>';
        }
});
```

Then as you add the table cells, add a row tag each time the first header is matched. Finish the row when the last header is matched.

It looks like the data appears in the column order. Something like this should work:

```
$.each(TblValues, function (i, item) {
    if (item.FieldType == 'TextBox') {

        if (item.Name === headers[0]) {
            tHTML += '<tr>';
        }

        tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><input type="text" id=' + item.Name + '0' + '  value=' + item.FieldValue + ' name=' + item.Name + '0' + ' placeholder=' + item.Name + ' class="form-control"/></td>';

        if (item.Name === headers[headers.length - 1] ) {
            tHTML += '</tr>';
        }
    }
});

console.log('tHTML\n' + JSON.stringify(tHTML));
```

Comment: The header section synatax is wrong throws error when placing code

Comment: I added the missing closing parenthesis after item.Name - headers.indexOf(item.Name). Hopefully that does it.

Comment: still same issue exists

Comment: I updated again and ran it this time.It had an extra parenthesis. The console.log shows valid html now. The syntax should be cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

You can take tr tag inside your each and check if count is multiple of 2 then open the tr tag else close tr tag.

```
$.each(TblValues, function (i, item) {
    if(i%2 == 0)
        tHTML += '<tr>';
                if (item.FieldType == 'TextBox') {

                        tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><input type="text" id=' + item.Name + '0' + '  value=' + item.FieldValue + ' name=' + item.Name + '0' + ' placeholder=' + item.Name + ' class="form-control"/></td>';
                    }                        else {
                        tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + '></td>';
                    }


 if(i % 2 == 1)
   tHTML += "</tr>";
});
```

Comment: This is a dynamic table so it has dynamic columns .Your code displays 2 columns in a row .But if it has more columns it wont work.so pls help me

Comment: @user4779701, given that your example/data only has two columns how would you expect someone answering your question to know that?

Comment: I have given the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Can u pls tell me what the number 2 represents

Comment: 2 is the number of columns. i % 2 means the remainder from dividing i by 2.  If i is less than 2 the answer to i % 2 will be i